# Thirsty rough regular font not working in smaller screens?

Tags: android, css, fonts

Thirsty rough regular font not working in smaller screens. In bigger screens, it's working but on smaller screens, it's totally not working.

```
@font-face {`enter code here`
    font-family: 'thirsty_roughregular';
    src: url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ThirstyRoughRegular.otf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/thirstyroughregular-webfont.svg#thirsty_roughregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

everIthing is perfect. but, is there anything else what i am missing to make it work for small screens.

Comment: Create a folder for different size and create dimen file inside that folder. (as per screen size)  `values`,`values-small`,`values-normal`,`values-large`,`values-xlarge`

Comment: Check the directory and linking.